# Liferay 7.3 - org.hibernate.MappingException: entity class not found

Tags: java, hibernate, liferay, liferay-7

I'm pretty new to Liferay development. I'm working on migrating a project from 6.2 to 7.3.

The plugin I'm working on has the -api / -service / -portlet structure that I've seen in the tutorials.

When I try to deploy the service JAR to my server, I'm getting the following error:

2021-07-07 10:30:11.759 ERROR [pipe-start 1356][LiferayServiceExtender:88] org.hibernate.MappingException: entity class not found: PhishRodLab.db.model.impl.Customer_PreferencesImpl
org.hibernate.MappingException: entity class not found: PhishRodLab.db.model.impl.Customer_PreferencesImpl
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getMappedClass(PersistentClass.java:125)
at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.getGetter(PropertyFactory.java:191)
at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildIdentifierProperty(PropertyFactory.java:67)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.(EntityMetamodel.java:135)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.(AbstractEntityPersister.java:485)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:133)
at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:84)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:286)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1872)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:795)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.hibernate.PortalHibernateConfiguration.newSessionFactory(PortalHibernateConfiguration.java:298)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:717)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.hibernate.PortalHibernateConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(PortalHibernateConfiguration.java:99)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.extender.internal.LiferayServiceExtender$LiferayServiceExtension.start(LiferayServiceExtender.java:148)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.extender.internal.LiferayServiceExtender.addingBundle(LiferayServiceExtender.java:83)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.extender.internal.LiferayServiceExtender.addingBundle(LiferayServiceExtender.java:61)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:475)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:1)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:229)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:450)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:908)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:230)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:137)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:129)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:191)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:578)
at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:449)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:428)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:447)
at org.eclipse.equinox.console.commands.EquinoxCommandProvider.start(EquinoxCommandProvider.java:243)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Reflective.invoke(Reflective.java:139)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:91)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:599)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:526)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:415)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.doCall(Pipe.java:416)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.call(Pipe.java:229)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.call(Pipe.java:59)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PhishRodLab.db.model.impl.Customer_PreferencesImpl
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:200)
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getMappedClass(PersistentClass.java:122)
... 49 more

Comment: is the -api project deployed already?

Comment: yes -api project is depolyed.

Comment: PhishRodLab.db.model.impl.Customer_PreferencesImpl not found.. seems to me you did not run service builder. Sometimes, rarely, I had to delete the generated code and regenerate it with a new version of service builder (probably the one that comes with your workspace)

Comment: could you please explain it more these are the things which I already tried but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered that error when migrating from previous versions when the DTD of the service.xml file is not the right one. You must make sure you are using the latest version available for the version you are using (7.3 in this case).
For example, the header of the service.xml file should start like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE service-builder PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Service Builder 7.3.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-service-builder_7_3_0.dtd">

<service-builder...>
```

The best option is to generate a test servicebuilder project using the tutorial, and then compare the generated code with yours, making note of the differences.

More info: https://help.liferay.com/hc/es/articles/360029028211-Introduction-to-Service-Builder

Comment: Have you used liferay IDE to generate the classes? It should be also in the latest version, if not, although in 7.3 version, it doesn't work properly

Comment: yeah am also using liferay developer studio

Comment: If so, try to update to the last version, in my case, I had the version to generate for 7.3.5, I thought it was valid for 7.3.6 too, but it wasn't. You should always have the latest version available